# Alternate for multiple try catch to handle the exception

Tags: java, java-8, try-catch, default-value, control-flow

I am trying to read a CSV file with 20 columns which may or may not contain value but the problem is that I have to create 20 try catch in order to maintain the code flow in control manner. Like

```
String a = ""; loop
try{
a = list.get(0);  // converted the csv to list of list and iterated in 
}catch(NoSuchElementException e){}
```

and same for every other variable.The reason I have seperate try catch because In the below code

```
 String a = ""; 
 String b = ""; 
 try{
    a = list.get(0);
    b = list.get(1);
 }catch(NoSuchElementException e){}
```

If first line of try gave exception the second line will not execute.

So is there any alternate to these n number of try catch situation?

Thanks

Comment: do it inside a loop and then remember how many columns are there using a counter

Comment: you can check the list `size` at the start

Comment: @sidgate the list size is same 20 for each row in csv for ex `code,1,,ee,de`.The list I get is something like this

Comment: how can you get `NoSuchElementException` if you are having the index within the list size?

Comment: What is the type of `list` ? [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) ?

Comment: (a) Don't try to put code in comments. If you want to specify the list you get, [edit] the question and add it there, properly formatted. (b) You can *always* avoid a `NoSuchElementException` by checking the list size. It will only be thrown if there are less than 20 elements in the list. (c) If you are handling a 20-field CSV by assigning each value to a variable, your program is probably unreadable.

Comment: A `List` implementation that behaves like you describe, i.e. throws a `NoSuchElementException` for an arbitrary element within the legal bounds should be considered broken. So the correct solution is to use a different CSV reader.

Comment: sorry for the late reply I was debugging my code. In the code I was using `Optional` which was causing the issue. It was completely my mistake that I dint post the complete code because I thought it would be irrevalant but I got the multiple try catch solution below thanks.

Comment: I see no try or catch in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a helper method:

```
private String getField(List<String> list, int n) {
  try {
    return list.get(n);
  } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    return "";
  }
}

String a = getField(list, 0);
String b = getField(list, 1);
```

EDIT:

Typically you wouldn't rely on exceptions if you do not have sufficient fields, the following achieves the same thing but subjectively feels cleaner:

```
private String getField(List<String> list, int n) {
  if (n < list.size()) {
    return list.get(n);
  }
  return "";
}
```

Comment: This is correct approach but in case of Exception I would prefer to log some information instead of returning empty string.

Comment: I would rather just check the list size instead of catching the exception

Comment: Returning the empty string is the behaviour described in the question. I agree that checking the list size is preferable but I wanted to illustrate the use of a helper method to avoid having lots of individual catch blocks...

Comment: The second approach is not just "subjectively" cleaner. An exception has extra overhead, as it creates a stack trace. If you check limits in advance, you have *objectively* better code.